# Pre-allocating a large file quickly in Linux with fallocate()

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

On Windows, seeking past EOF and truncating the file (via `SetEndOfFile()`) allows pre-allocating a large file without actually writing the extra zeroes to the disk *if*, afterwards, I write into the file sequentially (which I do).

How can I achieve the same effect in Linux? Seems like `ftruncate()` creates a sparse file which is not what I want because it doesn't decrease disk free space. That leaves me to `fallocate()` but which filesystems support this function exactly (natively, not emulated by glibc), or better yet:

**Which mainstream filesystems *do not* support `fallocate()`?**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Preallocate all required space to ensure later writes to the file do not fail because of lack of space?  [Red Hat says XFS, ext4, and GFS2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/main-fs) support preallocation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, that's one use case (which can be made optional to the user as a UX feature). Another use case is having a large mmapped file not crash due to disk full (but not take ages to create that file either).

Comment: *"Which mainstream filesystems do not support [file space manipulation]..."* seems like a question better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). I feel like you had a good programming question up until the point you asked for a list of filesystems with the feature. It seems like the natural question to ask was how to use `fallocate` or `posix_fallocate`.

Answer (score 2):

The operation is supported on at least the following filesystems:

- XFS (since Linux 2.6.38)
- ext4 (since Linux 3.0)
- Btrfs (since Linux 3.7)
- tmpfs(5) (since Linux 3.5)

Comment: I saw this on the manpage of fallocate(). So no ext3? Know of any other popular fs which doesn't have it? Thanks.

Comment: @cap I don't think ZFS does preallocation as you seem to require, and I also question the effectiveness of a preallocation ensuring adequate space exists for any COW filesystem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that adds ZFS and btrfs to the list then?